# Is it possible to Unit Test WinUI 3 code using NUnit?

Tags: nunit, winui-3

I've got a WinUI-3 solution with three projects: class libary for the backend and ViewModels, Unit testing via NUnit and a WinUI-3 app.

Everything was working fine with all tests passing until I called Colors.Transparent in one of my ViewModel methods (called from the ViewModel constructor), now *all* the tests for that ViewModel fail with:

```
        System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

  Stack Trace: 
RuntimeType.CreateInstanceOfT()
Activator.CreateInstance[T]()
WeakLazy`1.get_Value()
_IColorsStatics.get_Instance()
Colors.get_Transparent()
MainViewModel.ctor(IServiceProvider provider) line 58
MainViewModelTests.Constructor_SetsCachedSortedColumn_ToLTV() line 64
--COMException
BaseActivationFactory.ctor(String typeNamespace, String typeFullName)
_IColorsStatics.ctor()
RuntimeType.CreateInstanceOfT()
```

It looks like a dependency injection issue, any ideas how to get around this or does NUnit just not support WinUI-3?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example please?

Comment: I will later on when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an app that runs the tests on the UI thread as described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/winui-desktop-unit-tests?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

The idea is otherwise to keep your view models "free" from WinUI specific logic and tests these individually in a simple unit testing project.